# Grouping items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I require some assistance on how to transform an array with multiple objects where I want to group some of the types into one object. Specifically the ones with type "H*" and "text". So far I have this function

```
convert = () => {
let list = [];
let objBlock = {};
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    const element = content[i];
    if (element.type === 'H2' || element.type === 'H3' || element.type === 'text') {
        objBlock = { type: "text-block", content: element.html };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (
        element.type === 'list-pos-neg') {
        objBlock = { type: "list-pos-neg", content: element[Object.keys(element)[1]] };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (element.type === 'list-pos') {
        objBlock = { type: "list-pos", content: element[Object.keys(element)[1]] };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (element.type === 'list-neg') {
        objBlock = { type: "list-neg", content: element[Object.keys(element)[1]] };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (element.type === 'list-simple') {
        objBlock = { type: "list-simple", content: element[Object.keys(element)[1]] };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (element.type === 'image') {
        let content = element.content;
        if (!content)
            return;
        objBlock = { type: "image-block", content: content };
        list.push(objBlock);
    } else if (element.type === 'simple-btn') {
        objBlock = { type: "btn-simple", content: element[Object.keys(element)[1]] };
        list.push(objBlock);
    }
}
}
```

It gives me a list of all elements now with type and content fields. I want to group them now without interrupting the order in the list. I'm halfway here from what I can tell and now I'm stuck.

Plus, there's probably an easier method than I used here.

Here's an example of initial array:

```
{"contentBefore": [
    {
        "type": "H2",
        "html": "<h2>Header 2</h2>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Some Text <a href=\"https://let/me/out\">and</a> then some</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Some more text</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "Qs",
            "html": "<ul><li>Q1</li><li>Q2</li><li>Q3</li><li>Q4</li><li>Q5</li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "content": {
            "url": "qs.png",
            "altText": "qs",
            "seoImportant": true,
            "imgSrc": "",
            "imgEmbedded": false,
            "articleID": "artcile1234",
            "height": 700,
            "width": 1200
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Somebody</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>I used to know</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "H3",
        "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>More text</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<ol><li>1</li><li><a href=\"https://hear.com/me/out\">2</a></li><li>3</li></ol>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "1. Q1?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 1</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "2. Q2?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 2</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "H3",
        "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>More text?</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-pos",
        "pos": {
            "header": "Qq:",
            "html": "<ul><li><em>1</em></li><li><em>2</em></li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Even more text</p>"
    }
]}
```

Final result should look something like this:

```
{"contentAfter": [
    {
        "type": "text-block",
        "content": "<h2>Header 2</h2><p>Some Text <a href=\"https://let/me/out\">and</a> then some</p><p>Some more text</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "content": {
            "header": "Qs",
            "html": "<ul><li>Q1</li><li>Q2</li><li>Q3</li><li>Q4</li><li>Q5</li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "image-block",
        "content": {
            "url": "qs.png",
            "altText": "qs",
            "seoImportant": true,
            "imgSrc": "",
            "imgEmbedded": false,
            "articleID": "artcile1234",
            "height": 700,
            "width": 1200
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text-block",
        "content": "<p>Somebody</p><p>I used to know</p><h3>Header 3</h3><p>More text</p><ol><li>1</li><li><a href=\"https://hear.com/me/out\">2</a></li><li>3</li></ol>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "content": {
            "header": "1. Q1?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 1</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "content": {
            "header": "2. Q2?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 2</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text-block",
        "content": "<h3>Header 3</h3><p>More text?</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-pos",
        "content": {
            "header": "Qq:",
            "html": "<ul><li><em>1</em></li><li><em>2</em></li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text-block",
        "content": "<p>Even more text</p>"
    }
]}
```

Any tips?

Comment: what you mean with *"grouping"*?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59629797/edit) and then `[<>]` to make a [mcve]

Comment: 1st, it looks like you are doing the same thing for all of them except the `image` type.  2nd, I think `continue;` or `break;` instead of `return;` might suit your usecase better, hard to say.  ok, so your problem is what now?

Comment: @NinaScholz "grouping" was probably not the best description. I meant to collect objects with types h2,h3 and text that are next to the same type and combine them into one without messing up the order of other elements in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but here's a script that replicates the parts I was able to notice, and appears to me to create the output you give as sample output for the given input:

```js
const content = {"contentBefore": [
    {
        "type": "H2",
        "html": "<h2>Header 2</h2>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Some Text <a href=\"https://let/me/out\">and</a> then some</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Some more text</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "Qs",
            "html": "<ul><li>Q1</li><li>Q2</li><li>Q3</li><li>Q4</li><li>Q5</li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "content": {
            "url": "qs.png",
            "altText": "qs",
            "seoImportant": true,
            "imgSrc": "",
            "imgEmbedded": false,
            "articleID": "artcile1234",
            "height": 700,
            "width": 1200
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Somebody</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>I used to know</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "H3",
        "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>More text</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<ol><li>1</li><li><a href=\"https://hear.com/me/out\">2</a></li><li>3</li></ol>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "1. Q1?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 1</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "list-simple",
        "simple": {
            "header": "2. Q2?",
            "html": "<p><em>Big 2</em></p>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "H3",
        "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>More text?</p>"
    },
    {
        "type": "list-pos",
        "pos": {
            "header": "Qq:",
            "html": "<ul><li><em>1</em></li><li><em>2</em></li></ul>"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "html": "<p>Even more text</p>"
    }
]};

const getType = function(item) {
  if (/^H/.test(item.type) || item.type == "text") return "text-block";
  if (item.type == "image") return "image-block";
  // Looks like you may have more logic for this; not going to try to reproduce it
  return item.type;
}

let currentTextBlock = null;

content.contentAfter = content.contentBefore.reduce(function(result,item) {
   const type = getType(item);
   if (type == "text-block") {
     if (currentTextBlock) {
       currentTextBlock.content += item.html;
     } else {
       currentTextBlock = { type: "text-block", content: item.html };
       result.push(currentTextBlock);
     }
   } else {
     currentTextBlock = null;
     result.push(Object.assign({}, item, { type: type }));
   }
   return result;
}, []);


console.log(JSON.stringify(content,void(0),"  "))
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. Pardon for vague description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could group by all text and store the last text part for further use.

```js
var data = [{ type: "H2", html: "<h2>Header 2</h2>" }, { type: "text", html: "<p>Some Text <a href=\"https://let/me/out\">and</a> then some</p>" }, { type: "text", html: "<p>Some more text</p>" }, { type: "list-simple", simple: { header: "Qs", html: "<ul><li>Q1</li><li>Q2</li><li>Q3</li><li>Q4</li><li>Q5</li></ul>" } }, { type: "image", content: { url: "qs.png", altText: "qs", seoImportant: true, imgSrc: "", imgEmbedded: false, articleID: "artcile1234", height: 700, width: 1200 } }, { type: "text", html: "<p>Somebody</p>" }, { type: "text", html: "<p>I used to know</p>" }, { type: "H3", html: "<h3>Header 3</h3>" }, { type: "text", html: "<p>More text</p>" }, { type: "text", html: "<ol><li>1</li><li><a href=\"https://hear.com/me/out\">2</a></li><li>3</li></ol>" }, { type: "list-simple", simple: { header: "1. Q1?", html: "<p><em>Big 1</em></p>" } }, { type: "list-simple", simple: { header: "2. Q2?", html: "<p><em>Big 2</em></p>" } }, { type: "H3", html: "<h3>Header 3</h3>" }, { type: "text", html: "<p>More text?</p>" }, { type: "list-pos", pos: { header: "Qq:", html: "<ul><li><em>1</em></li><li><em>2</em></li></ul>" } }, { type: "text", html: "<p>Even more text</p>" }],
    last,
    targets = { 'list-simple': 'simple', 'list-pos': 'pos', image: 'content' },
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var type = o.type;

        if (['H2', 'H3', 'text'].includes(type)) {
            type = 'text-block';
            if (!last) r.push(last = { type, content: '' });
            last.content += o.html;
        } else {
            r.push({ type, content: o[targets[type]] });
            last = undefined;
        }

        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group like this. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
var data = [ { "type": "H2", "html": "<h2>Header 2</h2>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>Some Text <a href=\"https://let/me/out\">and</a> then some</p>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>Some more text</p>" }, { "type": "list-simple", "simple": { "header": "Qs", "html": "<ul><li>Q1</li><li>Q2</li><li>Q3</li><li>Q4</li><li>Q5</li></ul>" } }, { "type": "image", "content": { "url": "qs.png", "altText": "qs", "seoImportant": true, "imgSrc": "", "imgEmbedded": false, "articleID": "artcile1234", "height": 700, "width": 1200 } }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>Somebody</p>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>I used to know</p>" }, { "type": "H3", "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>More text</p>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<ol><li>1</li><li><a href=\"https://hear.com/me/out\">2</a></li><li>3</li></ol>" }, { "type": "list-simple", "simple": { "header": "1. Q1?", "html": "<p><em>Big 1</em></p>" } }, { "type": "list-simple", "simple": { "header": "2. Q2?", "html": "<p><em>Big 2</em></p>" } }, { "type": "H3", "html": "<h3>Header 3</h3>" }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>More text?</p>" }, { "type": "list-pos", "pos": { "header": "Qq:", "html": "<ul><li><em>1</em></li><li><em>2</em></li></ul>" } }, { "type": "text", "html": "<p>Even more text</p>" } ];


data.reduce(function(acc,val){
    if(acc[val["type"]]){
        acc[val["type"]].push(val);
    } else {
        acc[val["type"]] = [val];
    }
return acc;
},{});
```